# Getting access denied with RegCopyTree in C

Tags: c, winapi, registry

I am trying to use RegCopyTree to copy all the subkeys and values to another subkey, but I am getting error code 5, which means **ACCESS DENIED**.

I asked for `KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY` access, but It is still failing. I also ran the app as Administrator, but it did not work at all.

Can you help me?

Here is my code:

```
int wmain()
{
    //RegOpenKeyEx
    HKEY hKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    LPCWSTR subKeyOpen = L"WinSide";
    DWORD options = 0;
    REGSAM samDesired = KEY_READ;
    HKEY openedKey;

    //Opening the HKCU\WinSide subkey
    LONG openKey = RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, subKeyOpen, options,
                                    samDesired, &openedKey);

    LPCWSTR subKeyDest = L"WinSi";
    REGSAM destSamDesired = KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY;
    HKEY destOpenedKey;

    //Opening the HKCU\WinSi subkey - this is the destination subkey
    LONG destOpenKey = RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, subKeyDest, options,
                                destSamDesired, &destOpenedKey);


    if (openKey != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        wprintf(L"Error opening the key. Code: %li\n", openKey);
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"Key opened!\n");

        if (destOpenKey != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            wprintf(L"Error code: %li\n", destOpenKey);
        else
        {
            //RegCopyTree
            HKEY keyDest;

            LONG copyKey = RegCopyTree(openedKey, NULL, destOpenedKey);

            if (copyKey != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                wprintf(L"Error copying the key. Code: %li\n", copyKey);
            else
            {
                wprintf(L"Key copied!\n");
            }

        }



        RegCloseKey(openedKey);
        RegCloseKey(destOpenedKey);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried with `KEY_WRITE` in both openings but still the same error.

Comment: Just added the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved the issue:

Had to use `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` access right in the REGSAM variables. This way:

```
REGSAM samDesired = KEY_ALL_ACCESS;

REGSAM destSamDesired = KEY_ALL_ACCESS;
```

Comment: `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` seems required for the destination, but not the source key. Apparently, the docs are not correct here (according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regcopytreew), `KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY ` should be sufficient.